# How to tell whether a CmisObject represents a file or a folder?

Tags: cmis, dotcmis, opencmis

In OpenCMIS (or DotCMIS), how to tell whether a CmisObject represents a file or a folder?

Specification: http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.5.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/CmisObject.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
if (cmisObject instanceof Folder) { ... }
if (cmisObject instanceof Document) { ... }
```

And this works:

```
if (cmisObject.getBaseTypeId() == BaseTypeId.CMIS_FOLDER) { ... }
if (cmisObject.getBaseTypeId() == BaseTypeId.CMIS_DOCUMENT) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I have found (C# syntax):

```
cmisObject is DotCMIS.Client.Impl.Folder
```

Any better idea is welcome!

Comment: It's better to use the interface and not the implementation class: `cmisObject is IFolder`

Answer (score 0):

Florian Müller's answer adapted and tested for DotCMIS:

```
if (cmisObject is IFolder) { ... }
if (cmisObject is IDocument) { ... }
```